# How to stream data from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

The mongo `find()`, return all the documents in a collection. I want to store every document that I have in my mongodb in to another database. So, I want to keep polling mongodb for single new document, because `find().limit(1)` would keep returning me the same again and again. I just want mongo to return, all the document one by one. Is it possible? How can this be done?

Edit:
I want to just copy every entry in my mongodb instance to another db, not just the latest ones.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly: You want some way to monitor your MongoDB database in real-time and replicate each newly inserted document into a different database?

Comment: No, I want to just copy every entry in my mongodb instance to another db, not just the latest ones.

Comment: You can use the [db.copyDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) command for the initial copy.

Comment: There's also [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

Answer (score 3):

1. Use sort , by default it is a natural sort i.e.:

   find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)

You will need to store the _id of current document retreived and match it with the next one retreived with the same query, if they are different, you store the document, and also the new _id.

2. Better use tailable cursor :
   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Philipp's comment has the answer you're looking for, but to answer the original question:

I wouldn't suggest using a sort on the whole database if you expect your document sizes to be quite large, also a limit would result in horrible performance.

Running a find() operation actually returns a cursor object to you, which you can iterate upon, which is effectively streaming and therefore exactly what you're asking for.